# Eclipse console not displaying stdout

Tags: c, eclipse

Basically whenever there are command line arguments given to my app (using the box in Run/Run Configurations/Arguments), the Eclipse console will stop displaying the stdout (e.g. prtinf() commands) Is there any way to solve this? Am I inputting the command line arguments in the wrong place? (they are appearing in argv though)

Comment: I don't think this has something to do with the fact to pass arguments or not to the application unless your app/argmunent does any kind of standard stream redirection. In the launch configuration, there is an option "Connect process input & output to terminal" did you try to play with?

Comment: That is ticked but greyed out. I imagine I'd want it enabled though.